# Multipart uploaded s3 file returns incorrect etag

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, etag

I have a py function that does a multipart upload where the chunk size (max_file_size_MB) is set to **1MB**:

```
    def upload_file_to_aws(self, file_path, filename):
        
        MB = 1024 ** 2
        config = TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=self.max_file_size_MB * MB, max_concurrency=10,
                                multipart_chunksize=self.max_file_size_MB * MB, use_threads=True)

        try:
            self.client.upload_file(file_path, self.bucket_name, filename,
                                    ExtraArgs={'ContentType': 'application/json'},
                                    Config=config,
                                    Callback=ProgressPercentage(file_path))
        except ClientError as e:
            logging.error("Error uploading file to AWS. %s", e)
            return False
```

And I'm using the etag calculation algorithm from [here](https://github.com/antespi/s3md5)

I have the following unit test to make sure the etag calc function works fine which uses a **1.6MB** file

```
    @mock_s3
    def test_calculated_s3_etag_for_multipart_uploads_is_correct(self):
        # Run on a file of 1.6MB
        conn = boto3.resource('s3')
        conn.create_bucket(Bucket=self.client.bucket_name)

        calculated_etag = calculate_s3_etag(SNAPSHOT_DATA_LARGE_FILE)

        self.client.upload_file_to_aws(SNAPSHOT_DATA_LARGE_FILE, METADATA_ID)
        obj = self.client.get_object(self.client.bucket_name, METADATA_ID)
        uploaded_file_etag = obj['ETag']

        assert calculated_etag == uploaded_file_etag
```

but it fails with `assert '"bd86ed92459190f807e59b60b6089674-2"' == u'"eaa8602b7154cab4e0787756b2fdc53f-1"'`

The calculated etag looks alright but I'm not sure why the S3 etag looks like it was uploaded only in 1 chunk (when it should have been 2)

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT: So all of the above work fine *for any size file as long as the chunk size is more than **5MB***. If I want to transfer files in chunks less than 5MB I'm not sure what encoding technique is used (i can't use decoded md5 or the reversed engineered etag decoding)

Comment: That edit is the issue, from the docs: "Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum allowed object size. Each part must be at least 5 MB in size, except the last part."  If you need to upload smaller chunks, you'll need to upload them as separate S3 objects and somehow download and combine them elsewhere if they must be combined..

Comment: You're using moto to test this. I'm not certain, but I think perhaps moto doesn't correctly emulate the e-tag of multi-part uploads done with a single part. I think real S3 might convert them to a normal Put Object.

So try with real S3 to check the behavior is the same.